# Windows Azure Solr Error

Tags: azure, solr, lucene.net

I was trying [this](https://github.com/MSOpenTech/Windows-Azure-Solr/) thing on my local machine. I have 64bit win 8, and visual studio 2012 ultimate installed. Along with that I have JRE too. When I try to build the project, it's built without any issues. But when I try to execute the same I get error on the following line.

```
            var roleInstances = RoleEnvironment.Roles[bMaster ? "SolrMasterHostWorkerRole" : "SolrSlaveHostWorkerRole"].Instances;
```

as **role discovery data is unavailable**

Has anyone faced this kind of issue? And what to do to overcome it?? I read somewhere that

```
 <Runtime executionContext="elevated">
```

Should be added to service def file. But it's already there and not working :(

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you dump "RoleEnvironment.Roles" to see what is available? It is possble that they way you are reading the data is incorrect. Can u reduce your application to only 1 role and see what happens and this can help you to look further.

Comment: RoleEnvironment.Roles gives same error.. :(

Comment: [This](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazuretroubleshooting/thread/c80fe1eb-65f3-4b6b-934a-d7598cb4912c) link has helped me, I set up my cloud projects in the solutions as startup projects. But now I am facing another problem! for all runs which I tried system status remains blank and
Solr Master []: Not Ready 
Solr Slave #0 []: Not Ready 

Solr Slave #1 []: Not Ready 

is shown :(

Comment: can anyone tell me how do I run it?? I am not able to get those solr roles ready :( please somebody reply if  you faced and solved this issues :(

Comment: the issue is solved.
i used `Inst4WA.exe -XmlConfigPath "SolrInstEmul.xml"` and now it works :)